# Avoiding dynamic memory allocation on factorizing sparse matrix with Eigen

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, eigen3, matrix-factorization

In my application I need to avoid dynamic memory allocation (malloc like) except in the class constructors.
I have a sparse semidefinite matrix M whose elements change during the program execution but it mantains a fixed sparsity pattern.

In order to solve many linear systems M * x = b as fast as possible, the idea is to use inplace decomposition in my class constructor as described in [Inplace matrix decompositions](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__InplaceDecomposition.html), then call *factorize* method whenever M changes:

```
struct MyClass {
private:
    SparseMatrix<double> As_;
    SimplicialLDLT<Ref<SparseMatrix<double>>> solver_;
public:
    /** Constructor */
    MyClass( const SparseMatrix<double> &As ) 
        : As_( As )
        , solver_( As_ ) // Inplace decomposition
    {}

    void assign( const SparseMatrix<double> &As_new ) {
        // Here As_new has the same sparsity pattern of As_
        solver_.factorize( As_new );
    }

    void solve( const VectorXd &b, VectorXd &x )
    {
        x = solver_.solve( b );
    }
}
```

However *factorize* method still creates one temporary with the same size of *As_*, so using dynamic memory allocation.

Is it possible to avoid it in some way? If the Eigen API does not allow this feature, one idea is to create a derived class of SimplicialLDLT so that dynamic memory allocation is performed only in *analyzePattern* method that will be called in class constructor. Suggestions are welcome...

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible without several changes in the sparse solver logic (most importantly, you need a way to keep re-using memory for temporaries at several steps). I'd have to check the source again for a definitive answer, though.

Comment: If there is a chance I can implement this feature in a derived class. I think it's very useful for embedded and real-time applications where, very often, dynamic memory allocation is allowed only during the boot phase.

Comment: Another possible solution is to add a custom allocator to the solver constructor. Temporary matrices and vectors that should be dinamically allocated retrieve memory from the allocator. An allocator for real-time systems could be represented by a fixed size memory pool. This strategy could be useful in other contexts too.

Comment: Analyzing _SimplicialCholesky.h_ it's possible to avoid dynamic allocation using _Upper_ triangular part and _NaturalOrdering_.
To be precise, the first call to _factorize_ method still dynamically allocates memory but it can be done in class ctor.
Regarding ordering, it's possible to manually call _ordering_ method (in the ctor) as described here [link](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__OrderingMethods__Module.html) taking care to apply permutations to rhs and solution vectors.
The only concern is the indication _This module is currently for internal use only_ in documentation.

Comment: The idea partially works: using _NaturalOrdering_ prevents factorize method to allocate memory. On the other hand I need to manually permute the input matrix before running factorize method, that is: `H.selfadjointView<Upper>() = As_new.selfadjointView<Upper>().twistedBy(P);` and it creates temporaries. Any advice how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found a workaround using CSparse library to get H = P * A * P':

```
class SparseLDLTLinearSolver {
private:
    /** Ordering algorithm */
    AMDOrdering<int> ordering_;
    /** Ordering P matrix */
    PermutationMatrix<Dynamic, Dynamic, int> P_;
    /** Inverse of P matrix */
    PermutationMatrix<Dynamic, Dynamic, int> P_inv_;
    /** Permuted matrix H = P * A * P' */
    SparseMatrix<double> H_;
    /** H matrix CSparse structure */
    cs H_cs_;
    /** Support vector for solve */
    VectorXd y_;
    /** Support permutation vector */
    VectorXi w_;
    /** LDLT sparse linear solver without ordering */
    SimplicialLDLT<SparseMatrix<double>, Upper, NaturalOrdering<int>> solver_;
public:
    int SparseLDLTLinearSolver( const SparseMatrix<double> &A )
        : P_( A.rows() )
        , P_inv_( A.rows() )
        , H_( A.rows(), A.rows() )
        , y_( A.rows() )
        , w_( A.rows() )
    {
        assert( ( A.rows() == A.cols() ) && "Invalid matrix" );
        ordering_( A.selfadjointView<Upper>(), P_inv_ );
        P_ = P_inv_.inverse();
        H_ = A.triangularView<Upper>();
        H_.makeCompressed();
        // Fill CSparse structure
        H_cs_.nzmax = H_.nonZeros();
        H_cs_.m = H_.rows();
        H_cs_.n = H_.cols();
        H_cs_.p = H_.outerIndexPtr();
        H_cs_.i = H_.innerIndexPtr();
        H_cs_.x = H_.valuePtr();
        H_cs_.nz = -1;
        const cs_sparse A_cs{
            A.nonZeros(), A.rows(), A.cols(),
            const_cast<int*>( A.outerIndexPtr() ),
            const_cast<int*>( A.innerIndexPtr() ),
            const_cast<double*>( A.valuePtr() ),
            -1 };
        cs_symperm_noalloc( &A_cs, P_.indices().data(), &H_cs_, w_.data() );
        solver_.analyzePattern( H_ );
        // Factorize in order to allocate internal data and avoid it on next factorization
        solver_.factorize( H_ );
        /*.*/
        return -solver_.info();
    }

    int factorize( const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> &A )
    {
        assert( ( A.rows() == P_.size() ) && ( A.cols() == P_.size() ) &&
            "Invalid matrix size" );
        // Fill CSparse structure
        const cs_sparse A_cs{ 
            A.nonZeros(), A.rows(), A.cols(),
            const_cast<int*>( A.outerIndexPtr() ), 
            const_cast<int*>( A.innerIndexPtr() ), 
            const_cast<double*>( A.valuePtr() ), 
            -1 };
        cs_symperm_noalloc( &A_cs, P_.indices().data(), &H_cs_, w_.data() );
        solver_.factorize( H_ );
        /*.*/
        return -solver_.info();
    }

    void solve( const VectorXd &rhs, VectorXd &x )
    {
        assert( ( rhs.size() == P_.size() ) && ( x.size() == P_.size() ) &&
            "Invalid vector size" );
        // Solve (P * A * P') * y = P * b, then return x = P' * y
        y_ = solver_.solve( P_ * rhs );
        x.noalias() = P_inv_ * y_;
    }
};
```

*cs_symperm_noalloc* is a minor refactorization of *cs_symperm* function of CSparse library.

It seems to work, at least with my special problem. In the future it would be very useful if Eigen avoided creating temporaries (into the heap) for some sparse matrix operations.