# Eigen: selfadjointView does not work if innerIndexPtr vector is not well ordered

Tags: eigen, eigen3

Working on a realtime system, I use low level API to manipulate an Eigen sparse matrix in order to increase performances on a specific problem set.
In particular I mix Eigen with a variant of CSparse *cs_symperm* algorithm to get the permutation of A matrix: Ap = PAP'.
*cs_symperm* use the same low level structure for the sparse matrix but, for a fixed column, row indexes could be not well ordered.

This is a simple example, built by hand, of what could happen:

```
SparseMatrix<double> A( 2, 2 );
A.insert( 0, 0 ) = 1.0;
A.insert( 0, 1 ) = 2.0;
A.insert( 1, 1 ) = 3.0;
A.makeCompressed();
SparseMatrix<double> B = A;
B.innerIndexPtr()[0] = 0;
B.innerIndexPtr()[1] = 1; // <-- Not ordered
B.innerIndexPtr()[2] = 0; // <-- Not ordered
B.valuePtr()[0] = 1.0;
B.valuePtr()[1] = 3.0; // <-- Not ordered
B.valuePtr()[2] = 2.0; // <-- Not ordered
```

Here A and B are the same matrix. The only difference is the data order.

Matrix-vector product correctly works:

```
VectorXd x( 2 );
x << 1.0, 2.0;
VectorXd y = A * x;
VectorXd w = B * x;
assert( y( 0 ) == w( 0 ) ); // <-- OK
assert( y( 1 ) == w( 1 ) ); // <-- OK
```

*selfadjointView* does not work:

```
y = A.selfadjointView<Upper>() * x;
w = B.selfadjointView<Upper>() * x;
assert( y( 0 ) == w( 0 ) ); // <-- Fail!
```

The example in Eigen documentation (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html) shows ordered data but there's not an explicit indication.

Unfortunately I can't get Ap using Eigen because of dynamic allocation of temporaries objects. Any idea?

Test has been performed using Eigen v3.3.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort the entries of a matrix you can transpose it twice:

```
B = B.transpose(); B = B.transpose();
```

or you can transpose it once and use `selfadjointView<Lower>()`, or you can assign it to a row-major matrix (this implicitly transposes it as well):

```
SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> C = B;

w = C.selfadjointView<Upper>() * x;
```

Comment: It seems that it works only if an assignment is performed. Indeed the following does not work: residual.noalias() = b - B.transpose().selfadjointView<Lower>() * x

Comment: Yes, `B.transpose().selfadjointView<Lower>() ` is gets essentially optimized to `B.selfadjointView<Upper>()`

Comment: At the moment I've solved calculating matrix-vector product by hands. I'd rather not use CSparse algorithm to get Ap = PAP', but with Eigen this permutation creates temporaries and I can't allocate during runtime. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid, sorting by transposing will always create temporaries. (But it is O(n), in comparison to O(n*log(n)) for in-place sorting.) Theoretically, re-using `C` should not require re-allocation (but I'd need to check what Eigen actually does)

Comment: Btw to compute `w = Ap * x`, it is likely more efficient to permute the vectors instead of the matrix (unless you do this for a lot of vectors and the same matrix)

Comment: You are right, but my problem is a bit more complex and Ap is already built. The context is described in the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044017/avoiding-dynamic-memory-allocation-on-factorizing-sparse-matrix-with-eigen where H_ matrix is Ap in our post. Here I need to calculate the residual of the linear system solution in solve method, that is: P_ * rhs - H_.selfadjointView<Eigen::Upper>() * y_.